# Spring DI fails in 4.2.x but succeed in 4.3.x

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, guice, spring-java-config

I am trying to import Beans from Guice Injector in a spring based web app and then want those imported beans to be injected in subsequent creation of other beans.
How I am doing it:
I am trying to register guice Injector as bean. And then use getInstance to register other bean from guice based project as bean in my project.
In my java config :

```
@Bean
public Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.getInjector();
}
@Bean
@Inject
public ABC aBC(Injector injector) {
    return injector.getInstance(ABC.class);
}
```

Then one of my implementation is as

```
public class XYZ {
@Inject
XYZ (final ABC abc) {
}
```

When I use Spring 4.3.x this works but 4.2.x fails giving error No default constructor found.
Is there any difference between 4.3.x and 4.2.x Also I want to use 4.2.x only due to certain reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor injection was changed with 4.3, see https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3#implicit-constructor-injection-for-single-constructor-scenarios

You could try Autowired instead of Inject

```
public class XYZ {
   @Autowired
   XYZ (final ABC abc) {
}
```